# I am trying to reassign values in a loop but it does not change

Tags: python

The problem statement is, I should replace the any digit below 5 with 0 and any digit 5 and above with 1.

I am trying to reassign values, but it is not affecting, Why?

```
def fake_bin(x):    
    for i in x:
        if int(i) < 5:
            i = '0'
        else:
            i = '1'
    return i
```

Comment: What is `x`? A string? A list?

Answer (score -1):

You are out of loop and I doesnt represent anything at all in that context.

You need maybe to make array and store these values and return back